# Solr indexing in Apache Nutch crawler

Tags: apache-http-server, wiki, search-indexing

I am working with Apache Nutch crawler and followed guidelines mentioned in https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial. 
But when I am indexing, I got an error as followed.

Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/2xxxxxxxxxxxxx.

The input path at -filer is not a segment... skipping

Indexer: starting at 2019-04-02 14:16:21

Indexer: deleting gone documents: true

Indexer: URL filtering: false

Indexer: URL normalizing: true

No exchange was configured. The documents will be routed to all index writers.

Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
    type : Type of the server. Can be: "cloud", "concurrent", "http" or "lb"
    url : URL of the SOLR instance or URL of the Zookeeper quorum
    commitSize : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    auth : use authentication (default false)
    username : username for authentication
    password : password for authentication

Indexing 1/1 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:152)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:244)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing
`This IndexSchema is not mutable.`
in solr.log then, in solrconfig.xml, replace true with false in

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
```

It may then work or, at least, there'll be something more informative in solr.log

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and figured out that in Solr the core named 'nutch' was not mapped so I created a new core named 'nutch' from Solr > Core admin (http://localhost:8983/solr/#/) (created new folder named nutch and copied schema files) and it worked.